# tapestry 4 contrib table call getModel() multiple times

Tags: java, tapestry

```
public IBasicTableModel getModel() {
        return new IBasicTableModel() {

            public int getRowCount() {

                System.out.println("called many times....");
                return getServiceLayer().countTotalCategoryRow(getKeyword());

            }
}
```

when i tried this and printout on console, it showed this method getRowCount()
is called multiple times . Is this normal in tapestry 4?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've made any progress on this since November, but it could be called once during the initial render and once for the rewind cycle.

Also, your anonymous class that implements the `IBasicTableModel` needs to implement the method `getCurrentPageRows`--but you probably already know that ;)